# openshift how imagestream track the image changes?

Tags: openshift

I found that Openshift `ImageStream` concept are extremely difficult to understand. Openshift introduce one more abstract layer (compare to Kubernetes) to ensure:

> However, if the image stream tag used by the Deployment or Build is
>   not updated, then even if the Docker image in the Docker registry is
>   updated, the Build or Deployment will continue using the previous
>   (presumably known good) image.

I don't quite understand how this can be achieved? I read through `ImageStream`, `ImageStreamTag` and `ImageStreamImage`, they are just a pointer (or metadata) which pointing to external image. It doesn't contain actual image.

I can confirm that, after I created a `ImageStream` (which getting image from docker hub), the image is not pushing to Openshift default registry `docker-registry.default.svc:5000`, I inspect inside but couldn't find it. Vice versa it is valid, that mean if I push the image to default registry, the `ImageStream` will be created automatically.

Let's see the example below:

myImageStream:latest -> docker.hub/myNameSpace/myimage:latest (SHA-1234)

If I push a new image to docker.hub latest tag with SHA-5678, and if didn't set the ImageStream as `--scheduled`, that mean, my pod will always use the image SHA-1234.

Let's say if there is a new pod is spin up in another worker node, since the worker node doesn't have the image SHA-1234, it will start a fresh pull from docker.hub, and it will get SHA-5678.

This violate the so-called "known good image", and even worst because two different version of image are running. I am totally confused about this, can anyone give further explanation on how Openshift `ImageStream` works?

Reference:

https://blog.openshift.com/image-streams-faq/

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html#image-streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I access the default registry using [this](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/registry/accessing_registry.html). I scan through the images folder, my images indeed is not there. But then I pull the images in my master node via

```
docker pull docker-registry.default.svc:5000/NAMESPACE/REPO:TAG
```

I can successfully pull the images. After that, I push again the same image to the same registry `docker-registry.default.svc:5000`. Then in the registry path `/registry/docker/registry/v2`, my image is showing there.

This is very weird phenomena, I only have one registry running, but looks like it handle the images location differently.

Conclusively, by the way, Openshift indeed cache the specific image somewhere so even the actual remote docker image (in docker hub) is changed, it will always use the known-good version in the cache.